# Magento styles not loading for phtml file

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, css

i have created a custom module called Custom_AvailableOrders in which customers can add multiple items to cart, For this i had created a form for the customers to enter multiple products and when this form is submited its values is posted to indexcontroller.php and then i am filtering this products based on their stockavailablity and displaying them in display.phtml file as a new table.

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
    ->setData('products_notavailable',$Not_available_products)
    ->setData('products_available',$available_products) 
    ->setData('quantity',$submit_qty)       
    ->setTemplate('availableorders/display.phtml'); 
$this->renderLayout(); 
$this->getResponse()->setBody( $block->toHtml());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have to call `$this->getLayout()->loadLayout()` to load the update handles which add the CSS files.

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
    ->setData('products_notavailable',$Not_available_products)
    ->setData('products_available',$available_products) 
    ->setData('quantity',$submit_qty)       
    ->setTemplate('availableorders/display.phtml'); 
$this->getLayout()->setBlock('root', $block);
$this->renderLayout();
```